# Bold section headings in the Table of Contents of the Springer LNCS Template

Tags: table-of-contents, bold, lncs

I use the [Springer LNCS Template](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs) for my document and print the table of contents.

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\section{Literature Review}
\subsection{Method 1}
\subsection{Method 2}
\subsection{Method 3}
\section{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

The result with `\documentclass{llncs}` looks like this:

[image: Table of Contents with llncs]

---

I would like to change the appearance of the table of contents to have **bold section headings and page numbers** along with **more vertical spacing** between sections. How can I alter the template - or replace the TOC macro - such that it will look more like `\documentclass{article}`?

[image: Table of Contents with article]

Comment: If you intend to submit this, the editors will most likely reverse your changes, if you are not explicitly asked to make these changes.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for pointing that out. Though, I will use it for a different purpose here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying over the definition for section entries of `article` (because that one uses the formatting you want):

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@section[2]
  {%
    \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
      \addpenalty \@secpenalty
      \addvspace {1.0em \@plus \p@ }%
      \setlength \@tempdima {1.5em}%
      \begingroup
        \parindent \z@
        \rightskip \@pnumwidth
        \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
        \leavevmode \bfseries
        \advance \leftskip \@tempdima
        \hskip -\leftskip
        #1\nobreak
        \hfil
        \nobreak
        \hb@xt@ \@pnumwidth {\hss #2\kern -\p@ \kern \p@ }%
        \par
      \endgroup
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
\section{Literature Review}
\subsection{Method 1}
\subsection{Method 2}
\subsection{Method 3}
\section{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

[image]